# how to add gem dependency with :path and :branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rubygems

I am working on a rails gem that has dependency on the following

`gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'`

How can I add this in the gem spec as a dependency? Specifically I need to specifiy the path and branch in the dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to use Bundler then. You would put exactly what you have into the Gemfile file. Go checkout the link to Bundler I left below.

-- older info --

For jeweler you would add something like this:

```
gem.add_dependency 'authlogic', '> 1.0', '<= 2.0'
```

But you might be better off using Bundler. It's not just for rails: http://gembundler.com/

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the problem correctly. I need to specifiy the path and branch in the dependency

Comment: Also checkout this video for a very brief overview of Bundler: http://railscasts.com/episodes/201-bundler

Answer (score 1):

You need generate the gem. Publish it and after use this gem deploy.